# SQL AND OR query

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I am trying to select some messages from our customer service queries, WHERE Mmessage owner is ABC, data are LIKE ABCDEF AND message ... AND where the message is either from Customer to CSservice or from CSservice to Customer.

How can I do that?

```
SELECT Date, From, To, Data 
FROM Ccustomers WITH (NoLock)
WHERE MSGowner = 'ABC' AND Data LIKE '%ABCDEF%' AND 
([From] ='Customer' AND [To] = 'CSservice') OR ([From] ='CSservice' AND [To] = 'Customer') 

ORDER by Date
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the answer by jergen d, you just need an extra set of parentheses around the OR condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Date, From, To, Data 
FROM Ccustomers WITH (NoLock)
WHERE MSGowner = 'ABC' 
AND Data LIKE '%ABCDEF%' 
AND 
(
   ([From] = 'Customer'  AND [To] = 'CSservice') OR 
   ([From] = 'CSservice' AND [To] = 'Customer')
)
ORDER by Date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I have figured this out few seconds after posting message :) Still learning SQL :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query was basically correct. But you have to consider that the `and` connection is "stronger" than the `or`. To get to your desired output you need to set brackets.

Try this:

```
SELECT Date, [From], [To], Data 
FROM Ccustomers WITH (NoLock)
WHERE MSGowner = 'ABC' 
AND Data LIKE '%ABCDEF%' 
AND (([From] = 'Customer'  AND [To] = 'CSservice') OR ([From] = 'CSservice' AND [To] = 'Customer'))
ORDER BY Date;
```