# SQL - AND OR combination

Tags: sql, arcgis

This query works

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL
WHERE Date >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'
AND
CONFIDENCE <> 'Discarded'
AND 
CONTEXT <>'Home'
```

I want to be able to say:
And `(CONTEXT <> 'Home') OR (CONTEXT = 'Hospital' AND LOCAL = 1)`

So that I can select all records 
Either from April 2017 onwards, not discarded, that have a context not equal to home

OR

From April 2017 onwards, not discarded, OR with a context = hospital and local = 1.

I'm using ArcGIS. 
I have tried this:

```
"DATE_ENTER"  >= date '2017-04-04 00:00:00'
AND
"CONFIDENCE" <> 'Discarded'
AND 
(
("CONTEXT" <> 'Home address') OR ("CONTEXT" = 'Hospital' AND "LOCAL" = 1)
)
```

But there are still records with Context = Hospital and Local = 0

When I test

```
 ("CONTEXT" <> 'Home address')
```

or

```
("CONTEXT" = 'Hospital' AND "LOCAL" = 1)
```

alone, it works, I'm having trouble combining the two to give me what I need.

I had a look at this
[SQL AND OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168040/sql-and-or-query)

first.

Comment: for record where CONTEXT = 'Hospital' first par where you check ("CONTEXT" <> 'Home address') returns true, so it doesn't matter what is written in second or part. For more confusion please check sql truth table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRBgu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE Date >= '2017-04-04' AND  -- time component is unnecessary
  CONFIDENCE <> 'Discarded' AND 
  CONTEXT <> 'Home' AND NOT(CONTEXT = 'Hospital' AND LOCAL = 0)
```

Works

as does

```
    WHERE Date >= '2017-04-04' AND  -- time component is unnecessary
              CONFIDENCE <> 'Discarded' 
AND
    (
       ("CONTEXT" <> 'Home address' AND "CONTEXT" <> 'Hospital') 
       OR ("CONTEXT" = 'Hospital' AND "LOCAL" = 1)
    )
```

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really want:

```
WHERE Date >= '2017-04-04' AND  -- time component is unnecessary
      CONFIDENCE <> 'Discarded' AND 
      CONTEXT <> 'Home' AND
      (NOT (CONTEXT = 'Hospital' AND LOCAL = 1) )
```

When `CONTEXT = 'Hospital'`, then it is not equal to `'Home'`.  So, it still matches the condition on `CONTEXT`.

Comment: if in 4th condition you say that CONTEXT = 'Hospital', then there is no point to have 3rd condition.

Comment: Ok.I've tried to use 'CONTEXT <> 'Home' AND
      (CONTEXT = 'Hospital' AND LOCAL = 1). What happens is the one line that has Context = hospital and local =1 is returned. What I want is to first say: return all the <>home contexts. This is 400 lines. Then within this, exclude those lines where context = hospital and local = 1 (6 lines). this would leave me (counts toes) 394 lines. How do?

Comment: this should work:
CONTEXT <> 'Home' AND NOT(CONTEXT = 'Hospital' AND LOCAL = 1) 
Gordon almost got it right.

Comment: This seems to work, but for what I want local = 0. I changed it to that, and it appears to give me what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition should be like this :

```
...
AND 
(
   ("CONTEXT" <> 'Home address' AND "CONTEXT" <> 'Hospital') 
   OR ("CONTEXT" = 'Hospital' AND "LOCAL" = 1)
)
```

When you are using `("CONTEXT" <> 'Home address') OR ("CONTEXT" = 'Hospital' AND "LOCAL" = 1)` the result you are getting `But there are still records with Context = Hospital and Local = 0` is correct because of the first condition `"CONTEXT" <> 'Home address'`

Comment: This worked straight away. Thanks. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
(CONTEXT NOT IN('Hospital' , 'Home') OR (CONTEXT = 'Hospital' AND LOCAL= 1))
```